# Spring Security - @EnableGlobalWebSecurity deprecated to @EnableWebSecurity - CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot not loading properly afterwards

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

After upgrading from Spring Boot 2.3.0.RELEASE -> 2.7.8 and upgrading Spring Security from 5.7.6 -> 5.8.1, I only fixed the following deprecation - `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` to `@EnableMethodSecurity`

After making just that one change and re-running my Spock unit tests, I am continually getting the following root exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E: Method call: Method internalUser(java.lang.String) cannot be found on type org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionRoot
```

For some odd reason, the Spring Security Framework is no longer using my own CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot and seems to be defaulting back to its own `org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionRoot`

Here is my CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot.java:

```
package com.wellframe.excalibur.auth.accesscontrol;

import com.wellframe.excalibur.auth.AuthenticationHolder;
import com.wellframe.excalibur.auth.UserType;
import com.wellframe.excalibur.services.GambitService;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.security.access.expression.SecurityExpressionRoot;
import org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionOperations;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;

/\*\*

* Custom methods defined here will be accessible by spring security method annotations like @PreAuthorize.
  \*/
  public class CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot extends SecurityExpressionRoot implements
  MethodSecurityExpressionOperations {

  private final GambitService gambitService;

  public CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication, ApplicationContext context) {
  super(authentication);
  gambitService = context.getBean(GambitService.class);
  }

  public boolean gambitAuthorize(AccessControlPolicy... policies) {
  return gambitService.authorizeRequest((AuthenticationHolder) super.getAuthentication(), List.of(policies));
  }

  public AccessControlPolicy internalUser(String methodName, Object... args) {
  return new AccessControlPolicy(UserType.INTERNAL_USER, methodName, args);
  }

  public AccessControlPolicy careManager(String methodName, Object... args) {
  return new AccessControlPolicy(UserType.DASH_USER, methodName, args);
  }

  public AccessControlPolicy programUser(String methodName, Object... args) {
  return new AccessControlPolicy(UserType.MOBILE_USER, methodName, args);
  }

  // Copied from Spring Security's access/expression/method/MethodSecurityExpressionRoot.java
  private Object filterObject;
  private Object returnObject;
  private Object target;

  @Override
  public void setFilterObject(Object filterObject) {
  this.filterObject = filterObject;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getFilterObject() {
  return filterObject;
  }

  @Override
  public void setReturnObject(Object returnObject) {
  this.returnObject = returnObject;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getReturnObject() {
  return returnObject;
  }

  void setThis(Object target) {
  this.target = target;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getThis() {
  return target;
  }
  }
```

Here is my CustomCustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler.java:

```
package com.wellframe.excalibur.auth.accesscontrol;

import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler;
import org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionOperations;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;

/\*\*

* Used to provide custom security expressions in the @PreAuthorize annotation.
  \*/
  public class CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler extends DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler {

  private ApplicationContext context;

  public CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler() {
  String stopHere = "stopHere";
  }

  @Override
  protected MethodSecurityExpressionOperations createSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication,
  MethodInvocation invocation) {

       CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot root = new CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot(authentication, this.context);
       root.setThis(invocation.getThis());
       root.setPermissionEvaluator(getPermissionEvaluator());
       root.setTrustResolver(getTrustResolver());
       root.setRoleHierarchy(getRoleHierarchy());
       root.setDefaultRolePrefix(getDefaultRolePrefix());
       return root;

  }

  @Override
  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
  super.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
  this.context = applicationContext;
  }
  }
```

and finally, here is my MethodSecurityConfig.java:

```
@EnableMethodSecurity
//@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;
    
    @Bean
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setApplicationContext(context);
        return expressionHandler;
    }

}
```

The only change that I made was fix the deprecation. @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true) to @EnableMethodSecurity.

After making that change, and stepping through the code, I realized that the Spring Security framework is no longer calling my @Override method in my CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler.java:

```
    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionOperations createSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication,
        MethodInvocation invocation) {
    
        CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot root = new CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot(authentication, this.context);
        root.setThis(invocation.getThis());
        root.setPermissionEvaluator(getPermissionEvaluator());
        root.setTrustResolver(getTrustResolver());
        root.setRoleHierarchy(getRoleHierarchy());
        root.setDefaultRolePrefix(getDefaultRolePrefix());
        return root;
    }
```

Comment: Any luck fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [migration guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/authorization.html#_id_still_prefer_to_subclass_defaultmethodsecurityexpressionhandler), you now have to override `createEvaluationContext` instead of `createSecurityExpressionRoot` in your `CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler`.